# Kendo UI Toolbar and Grid - strange save behavior when triggered from Toolbar control

Tags: kendo-ui

I have some pages where I have a kendo ui grid (wired up to full CRUD services), but use a separate Kendo UI Toolbar control (as opposed to the toolbar configuration in the grid itself).  I have a number of different buttons/menus on the toolbar, but am seeing a strange behavior when calling saveChanges() on the grid.  If a cell is being edited when the save button is clicked, the grid is saved, but the edited value is lost (it reverts back to where it was).  The following details what I see in different situations:

1. When using a save button configured in the grid (command: "save"), any changes in a cell being edited are committed with the save.
2. When using a plain html button that calls the saveChanges() method of the grid, any changes in a cell being edited are committed with the save.
3. When using a save button configured in a toolbar control, the changes in a cell being edited are LOST when saveChanges() is called.

The following jsbin shows the behavior of all three:

http://jsbin.com/jazobexatu/2/edit?html,js,output

I have tried calling the save from the toolbar button a number of different ways (even trying to trigger the click event of the external button), but nothing seems to correct the behavior.  I also tried calling closeCell() on the grid (to try to force the value back into the data, but that doesn't work either).  I haven't been able to debug the javascript enough to figure out what is different.  I'm hoping someone with a deeper understanding of these controls can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the mouse down event on the toolbar button doesn't cause a blur on the editor.

You can try it yourself by clicking in the cell to edit it, then click and hold the mouse button down on the "normal" button. The editor closes on mouse down, causing a blur of the editor, and persists the change.

If you do the same thing, click and hold mouse down, on the toolbar button, the editor stays open.

I've been poking through the source, but haven't figured out exactly why this happens. My best guess would be that the mousedown handler on the toolbar prevents the event from bubbling or running its default action and the editor doesn't blur.

---

Additional detail: On mousedown on the grid header button and the normal button, the focused element changes (which is what causes the editor blur). But on mousedown of the toolbar button, the editor input element still has the focus.

Shifting the focus on mousedown of the toolbar might be a workaround.

---

Sort of a weird hack, but this works in Chrome (any should in any browser that supports `activeElement`

```
click: function (e) {   
    $(document.activeElement).blur();
    $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();  
}
```

Comment: Awesome.  I was looking for just such a hack - just didn't know how to make it happen myself.  Thanks!